# Facing issue in external graphic using GeoTools(version 26.2)

Tags: java, svg, geotools

Not able to generate SVG from an external graphic link using an SLD file. Please go through the below code snippet,

Sld file with an external link,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
   <NamedLayer>
      <Name>Grass</Name>
      <UserStyle>
         <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
               <PointSymbolizer>
                  <Graphic>
                     <ExternalGraphic>
                        <OnlineResource xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Map_marker.svg" xlink:type="simple" />
                        <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                     </ExternalGraphic>
                     <Size>20</Size>
                  </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
         </FeatureTypeStyle>
      </UserStyle>
   </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Export SVG code

```
 private static Style loadStyle(String sldFilename) throws IOException {
    StyleFactory factory = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory(null);

    File file = new File("C:\\poc\\" + sldFilename);
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();

    SLDParser stylereader = new SLDParser(factory, url);

    Style style = stylereader.readXML()[0];
    return style;
}

public static DefaultFeatureCollection createBoundingBox(Coordinate[] listofP){
    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
    b.setName("MyFeatureType");
    b.add("location", Polygon.class);
    final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = b.buildFeatureType();
    SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
    Polygon polygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(listofP);
    featureBuilder.add(polygon);
    SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature("polygon");
    DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", TYPE);
    featureCollection.add(feature); //Add feature 1
    return featureCollection;
}

  public static void exportSVG(String fileName, Coordinate[] listofP)
        throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    Style pStyle = loadStyle(fileName);

    MapContent map = new MapContent();

    DefaultFeatureCollection boundingbox = createBoundingBox(listofP);
    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(boundingbox, pStyle);
    map.addLayer(layer);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    // Create an instance of org.w3c.dom.Document
    Document document = db.getDOMImplementation().createDocument(null, "svg", null);

    // Set up the map
    SVGGeneratorContext ctx1 = SVGGeneratorContext.createDefault(document);
    SVGGeneratorContext ctx = ctx1;
    ctx.setComment("Generated by GeoTools2 with Batik SVG Generator");

    SVGGraphics2D g2d = new SVGGraphics2D(ctx, true);

    Dimension canvasSize = new Dimension(1024, 1024);
    g2d.setSVGCanvasSize(canvasSize);

    StreamingRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
    renderer.setMapContent(map);

    Rectangle outputArea = new Rectangle(g2d.getSVGCanvasSize());
    ReferencedEnvelope dataArea = map.getMaxBounds();

    renderer.paint(g2d, outputArea, dataArea);
    File fileToSave = new File("C:\\poc\\" + "markers.svg");

    OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileToSave);
        osw = null;

        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8");
        g2d.stream(osw);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  finally {
        if (osw != null)
            try {
                osw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    mc.dispose();
}
```

Using the above code and SLDfile the final SVG is not getting rendered properly, its final output SVG image shows only a gray square. Instead it should show the exact marker present on the external link. Tried using the local SVG external link as well but still no luck.

[Final Output Using SLD file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6UAX.png)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BL3yO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Also, it would help enormously if you make a small, self-contained, compileable example that demonstrates the problem. Your example code won't compile.

Comment: @BradHards added the remaining code. To pass the value of coordinate please see below example,
Coordinate[] listOfPoints = new Coordinate[5];
        listOfPoints[0] = new Coordinate(-73.82, 41.24);//add random value of lat, long

Comment: That isn't what I meant. What is `map` in that? Where are the imports? Please read http://sscce.org/ and consider that if you are much more likely to get help if you make it easy to help you. Try to make a really small example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @BradHards please check now.

Comment: This issue is resolved for me. The bug is due to missing library batik-codec and firewall issues for the external links.

Comment: OK. You still didn't provide a reproducable test case, but you can make an answer ("Your Answer", below) that explains what you needed to do to fix it.